# Unable to connect to mongolab host

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I am trying to connect to mongolab from terminal via below command

```
 mongo ds061158.mongolab.com:61158/order_it -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```

I am getting the below error.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
connecting to: ds061158.mongolab.com:61158/order_it
2014-07-09T13:52:44.890+0530 Error: couldn't connect to server ds061158.mongolab.com:61158 (23.22.170.205), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

What has to be done in this case?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is `61158` the correct port? It is not the default mongo port (27017)

Comment: Yes, it is correct I see the same port in my mongolab home page.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like your network is blocking access to that port. I'd recommend contacting your network administrator or trying from a different network.

To test your network connectivity alone (no credentials necessary) you can run this command. This example was run from my unprivileged laptop just now and demonstrates a successful test.

```
% mongo ds061158.mongolab.com:61158
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: ds061158.mongolab.com:61158/test
rs-ds061158:PRIMARY> db.runCommand({ping:1});
{ "ok" : 1 }
rs-ds061158:PRIMARY> exit
bye
```

Our full connectivity troubleshooting guide is here: http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#help

Also, feel free to contact us as support@mongolab.com if you'd like us to dig into the specifics of your server or code. We're always happy to help!

Regards,

Jared

Comment: Thanks Jared. My firewall was preventing this.

Comment: can you elaborate more on "network is blocking access to that port"? do you mean the open ports for my laptop?

Comment: @Pierrew: The issue could be anywhere between the client and the server. MongoLab does allow configuration of firewall rules for Dedicated plans, but that did not seem to be the issue here, as I was able to connect to the port from an unprivileged network. Often, local networks or even the OS you're running on your client will have outbound firewall rules. Your local network administrator will be able to help diagnose such situations and is probably the only person who can poke a hole in the firewall for you if needed.

Comment: @jared can you look into this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060880/mongoerror-failed-to-connect-to-server-on-first-connect

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but in case someone still faces a similar issue, this is what helped me:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongodb restart
```

Answer (score -2):

You should try to explicitly specify the port you want to use with the `--port` option:

```
mongo ds061158.mongolab.com/order_it --port 61158 -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```

From the `mongo` man pages:

> **`--port <port>`**
>                 Specifies the port where the **mongod** or **mongos** instance is listening. Unless specified mongo connects to mongod instances on port **27017**, which is the default mongod port.

Comment: No this does not work with URL. I got this error "MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
url can't have host or port if you specify them individually"

Comment: @hannanessay - yes... specify the port in a n option and remove it from your URL.

Comment: Command I used is this "mongo ds061158.mongolab.com/order_it --port 61158 -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>" - I have removed the port from URL. Still I get the error "MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3 url can't have host or port if you specify them individually"