# Mongo Network Error Failed to Connect to Server on First Connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I attempt a GET request from my mlab db, I get the following error:
(node:47578) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [ds157439.mlab.com:57439] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection timed out]

It was working but when I came back to the code a few hours later, I got this error.

Comment: Explanation why you error may have occurred are to be found on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060880/mongoerror-failed-to-connect-to-server-on-first-connect

Comment: I have a user and password created on mlab.

Comment: Could it be an issue with mlab, maybe there are having problems with their servers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further digging, I found out that MLAB is run on AWS and that AWS for my region was down during the time I was attempting to connect to MLAB.

Answer (score 0):

I Faced the similar issue.
I updated the connection string and the application was up and running:

`Go to Mongo DB` -> `Cluster` -> `Connect` -> `Connection string`